# Is IllegalStateException: No entry found for connection a recoverable exception for KafkaConsumer.poll?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a KafkaConsumer where the following error is logged

```
Heartbeat thread failed due to unexpected error java.lang.IllegalStateException: No entry found for connection 1
```

followed by `KafkaConsumer.poll()` throwing the `IllegalStateException`.

In this case can I continue to call `KafkaConsumer.poll()` with the expectation that it will reconnect and continue to function?

Or is this an unrecoverable error that means I can no longer use this consumer?

Comment: What's your Kafka version? Is this a one-off or are you repetitively hitting this issue? If you can reproduce, can you attach TRACE logs?

Comment: If occurred with 2.2.0 broker and 2.1.1 clients. It happened with multiple consumers running in k8s pods when the network interface was brought down on the node to test HA. I might be able to get some trace logs when I next test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying cause of this issue was [KAFKA-7974](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7974) so it isn't an exception you'd be expected to recover from as the internals of the consumer should handle this case.

It will be resolved in Kafka 2.1.2, 2.2.1 and 2.3.0.